# Aluminum Activation

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics

StackExchange. Long time reader, first time asker.

So I'm trying to calculate a prediction for a radiation spectrum of Activated Aluminum, an example of which is shown below.

[image]

[The Paper I got that graph from and one of my main sources is shown here - https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00223131.2018.1461694?needAccess=true ]

$A = \frac{\lambda C}{(1-e^{-\lambda t_i})(e^{\lambda t_c})(1 - e^{-\lambda t_m})\epsilon b \mu}$

Where C is the count of a gamma-peak, lambda is the decay constant, $t_i$ is the irradiation time, $t_c$ is the cooling time, $t_m$ is the measurement time, $\epsilon$ is the detection efficiency, b is the branching ratio, and $\mu$ is the photon self-absorption constant of the sample in the sample.

My first attempt was an incoherent failure so I'm trying again and could use some advice. The goal is to find the "expected activity" which I assume is to create a graph like this but under different circumstances.

A.) Target is bombarded with a stream of Protons, assuming each Proton involved has an energy of about 800 MeV.

B.) Proton Flux of about 10^16 protons/cm^2 with a circular target area that has a diameter of 6mm and a thickness 0.25mm made of 99.999% pure Aluminum.

C.) Target is irradiated for 2 days then allowed to rest allowed to rest for 365 days.

My second attempt so far seems like it will do better at getting estimate but it's based on some rather sweeping assumptions.

A.) The location of the peaks in this graph won't change by any real amount, just the intensity.

B.) The shape of the curves will be similar except where it's had time to decay down into Noise.

C.) The Noise band starts at about 10 counts.

With those assumptions I can just concentrate on the peaks, figuring out how they start and from there where they'll decay too. Given the half-lives of 7-Be, 22-Na, and 24-Na I further probably only really need to worry about 22-Na. The paper includes some handy equations.

My gut says though there's a better way, but one I don't know. Willing to take any advise or help.

Edit:- I did change the link to the paper. That should help at least. Not entirely sure how to enter math here.

Edit 2:- Still hearing about a paywall. Weird, but I think I can put up some math now.

Comment: The paper is behind a paywall. I suggest that you provide any relevant handy equations.

Comment: I'm still pondering how to get some of those isotopes. a (p,$\alpha$) reaction ends up with 24-Mg, so to get to 24-Na you need a second (p,n) reaction. Getting to 22-Na is harder to figure out, much less 7-Be.

Comment: Having trouble getting the equations in, but you should be able to see the original paper now.

Comment: The link you have in the question is still behind a paywall .Is this the paper?  http://www.aesj.net/document/pnst006/171_174.pdf

Comment: It is not. But actually I got something figured out. Something good enough for my research advisor at least. Still want to get better if I find it.

The paywall thing is a pickle.